# Button resizes on > 2.3.6

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

This is what is happening:

[image: button resizes horizontally in gt 2.3.6]

This is the source image:

[image: source image]

This is part of the xml layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_headers"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/etNewItem"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:completionThreshold="2"
        android:dropDownHeight="wrap_content"
        android:dropDownWidth="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/et_newitemhint"
        android:inputType="text|textCapSentences"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        style="@style/DialogEditText"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_add"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the Selector xml for the button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_focused="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_add_pressed"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_add_pressed"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_add_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Why is this button horizontally resizing in 4.x.x? The source graphic did use to be a 9-patch, but it did exactly the same thing, so I changed it to a normal png, with no result.

The odd thing is is that this is the only graphic which exhibits this behaviour. I have it in an actionbar somewhere: same thing; I have it in a dialog too: same thing.

My 2.2.2 and 2.3.6 test devices show the button as it should be, but any of my test devices of 4.x.x show the elongated button.

Comment: Just a stab in the dark, but have you tried using a `ImageButton` instead of a `Button` and setting the drawable via `android:src=".."` instead of `android:background=".."`? I wonder if using the background attribute isn't allowing the button to measure its size properly, hence the weird result,

Comment: Thanks for your advice @AlexMDC, your solution may have worked, but I went straight for the code from androbat, which did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First, make these:**

res/drawable/button_add_normal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_add_normal"
    android:tileMode="disabled" 
    android:gravity="top" >
</bitmap>
```

res/drawable/button_add_pressed.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/btn_add_pressed"
    android:tileMode="disabled" 
    android:gravity="top" >
</bitmap>
```

**Then use this as selector:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
     <item android:state_focused="true" 
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_pressed"/>
     <item android:state_pressed="true" 
           android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_pressed"/>
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_add_normal"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to reproduce this on my devices. However, I still have a solution: you can use exact sizes like this:

```
android:layout_width="50dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
```

This way the image should look the same on every device.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Malcolm; but I was remiss in stating that I have a version of this graphic for ldpi, mdpi, hdpi & xhdpi resolutions; so setting a fixed size isn't an option.

Comment: @DaveSav But the size is set in density-independent pixels, it will scale automatically. And you can even use a dimension and enter different numbers for each density (though this is an overkill in your case).

Comment: Really? But won't the visual quality of the graphic degrade as it scales up? The source graphic I gave was for mdpi; how would that look scaled up to xhdpi?

Comment: @DaveSav No, no, the pixel value will scale. So `50dp` will mean `50px` for mdpi, `75px` for hdpi, and so on. The graphics will be what you provide for the specified pixel density. Since you have pictures for all the densities, everything will look well.